# Extending monadic predicate calculus

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

If we used currying to extend monadic predicate calculus to polyadic predicates, would validity of a formula in this predicate calculus be decidable? Why or why not?

EDIT: I am led to believe that that calculus would be undecidable. If that is right, why would currying monadic predicates not suffice to maintain decidability?

Comment: See George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, [Computability and Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=nnAhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA270) (5th ed - 2007), page 270 : "[According to] Church’s theorem first-order logic is undecidable [...]. " 1/2

Comment: "This negative result leaves room on the one hand for contrasting positive results, and on the other hand for sharper negative results. The most striking of the former is the Lowenheim–Behmann theorem, to the effect that the logic of monadic (one-place) predicates is decidable, even when the two-place logical predicate of identity is admitted. The most striking of the latter is the Church–Herbrand theorem that the logic of a single dyadic (two-place) predicate is undecidable." 2/2

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA as I expected but can you answer the follow-up in my edit? Preferably with a proof?